# Select rows where array contains one of several values in bigquery (ideally with dbplyr)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, dbplyr

I have a large set of tweets on bigquery and now want to filter those that contain at least one of a list of hashtags. The hashtags are saved in an array column (uploaded from a list column in R). How can I select rows that contain one of multiple values in any place in that array?

Below the code that I would use for the analysis in R. Unsurprisingly, `dbplyr` cannot translate the `purrr` part, and I am happy to learn to create the SQL myself, but haven't yet found a good starting point. Thanks for any pointers.

PS: I have not yet uploaded the Tweets to bigquery, they currently live in 80 GB of RDS filed. If any simple data transformation would make this easier, I could still include that while uploading.

```
tweets_sample <- tibble::tribble(
  ~text, ~hashtags,
  "Hello", list("World", "You"),
  "Goodbye", list("Friend", "You"),
  "Not", list("interested")
)

hashtag_list <- c("World", "interested")

tweets_sample %>% filter(purrr::map_lgl(hashtags, ~ .x %in% hashtag_list %>%
                                   any()))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difficult part here is that your hashtags column is of type list or array. As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64124013/postgres-generate-array-using-slide-window) dbplyr translation for more advanced data types like arrays does not appear to be well established.

Two alternative approaches:

1. Convert your hashtags to a character string and use text search (grep).
2. Write a bigquery query as a character string in R and attach it to an existing connection. Here is an example:

```r
db_connection = DBI::dbConnect( ... ) # connect to database
remote_tbl = dplyr::tbl(db_connection, from = "remote_table_name")

# build SQL query
sql_query <- glue::glue("SELECT *\n",
                        "FROM (\n",
                        "{dbplyr::sql_render(remote_tbl)}\n",
                        ") alias\n",
  
new_remote_table = dplyr::tbl(db_connection, dbplyr::sql(sql_query))
```

Comment: Thanks! In this case, (1) might actually work well, particularly because it makes it easier to deal with similar but not identical hashtags. Re 2,, just for reference, I did some digging and found that the bigquery SQL would need to be sth like the following: 

SELECT *
FROM `tweets1`
WHERE ('WomensDay' IN UNNEST(hashtags) OR 'Eurovision' IN UNNEST(hashtags) OR 'brexit' IN UNNEST(hashtags))